# Conditional Trigonometric Identities

Tags: trigonometry

If $A+B+C=\pi,\  $ then prove that:
$$\sin(B+2C)+\sin(C+2A)+\sin(A+2B)=4\sin\dfrac{B-C}2\sin\dfrac{C-A}2\sin\dfrac{A-B}2$$

I only get $A+B+C=\pi$ from the question and both the LHS & RHS are out of my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin(B+2C)=\sin\{B+C+A+C-A\}=\sin\{\pi+(C-A)\}=-\sin(C-A)$$

Observe that $\sum_{\text{cyc}}(C-A)=0$

A little **generalized proof**: if $2x+2y+2z=4n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,
$$\sin2x+\sin2y+\sin2z=2\sin(x+y)\cos(x-y)+2\sin z\cos z$$

$$=2\sin(2n\pi-z)\cos(x-y)+2\sin z\cos\{2n\pi-(x+y)\}$$

$$=-2\sin z\cos(x-y)+2\sin z\cos(x+y)$$

$$=-2\sin z[\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)]$$

$$=-2\sin z(2\sin x\sin y)$$

Here $n=0,2x=C-A$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I can't edit posts.

Use the following identities for the left side:

$sin(α + β) = sin(α)cos(β) + cos(α)sin(β) 
sin(α – β) = sin(α)cos(β) – cos(α)sin(β) 
cos(α + β) = cos(α)cos(β) – sin(α)sin(β) 
cos(α – β) = cos(α)cos(β) + sin(α)sin(β)$

What's on the right side of the proof isn't understandable, try fixing it up and I can attempt to solve it.